# How to keep active bootstrap tooltip without hover or click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**This is example which i am using for keep open tooltip without hover or click
but its not working any other suggestion**

```
<a href="#" title="Download Excel" class="tool_tip">Download Excel</a>
```

my jquery for tooltip keep active

```
<script>
    $('.tool_tip').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
</script>
```

Comment: can you give complete html and jquery code including which reference file you are using

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
```

to your html:

```
 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Download Excel" class="tool_tip">Download Excel</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/404c3fxb/

Or, you can do it with jQuery, for all the elements you want to, with a class selector:

```
$('.tool_tip')
  .attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
  .attr('data-placement', 'right')
  .tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual'
  })
  .tooltip('show');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/404c3fxb/1/

Where **data-placement** is the tooltip location (left, top, bottom or right).

[Bootstrap tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Comment: i used jquery for that

Comment: this does not work properly when the tooltip is inside a collapsible

Comment: @xhafan I believe there are always conditions when a code snippet would not work.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4.x - **JS**

`$('#IDENTIFIER').css({'pointer-events': 'none'}).tooltip('show');`

Bootstrap 4.x - **CSS**

`#IDENTIFIER# { pointer-events: none; }`

This way the parent-element (of the tooltip) will ignore all click-events - so the tooltip is always visible.